# Set height of content inside google maps info window

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jqtouch

When I instantiate a google maps info window, it doesn't resize the window to match the content's height. Instead, it adds a scrollbar. In fact, it doesn't even seem to use all the available height of the window itself, instead instituting some arbitrary size. Any idea how to get this to manually resize itself? You can see the issue here, by clicking on "contact", and then clicking on one of the markers.

http://presentations.superfaddev.com/ifad/v2/ifad.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's a much better way to handle infoWindows, which is to use the infoBox extension, hosted here:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/

and documented here:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/

which solves this and many other problems with google's infowindow.